# Can't display image because it contains errors

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have been trying to display an image in PHP for the last 3 hours. I followed a few threads on how to achieve this and pass 2 hours on stackoverflow and other forum to try to fix the problem.

The following code is a trim down of the one I use. (I have more code to handle jpeg, png and different SQL tables)

**MySQL Settings**

I have a table called *teams* in which I have these 3 values : *id*, *image* and *mime*

**Current PHP Code**

I have a file called show_image.php for which I pass an id to get the right image.

```
if(isset ($_get['id'])) {
    $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query = 'SELECT `image` FROM `teams` WHERE `id` = ?';

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($image);
            $stmt->fetch();
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');    // I can use the DB query to change the type is needed
            echo $image;
        }
    }
}
```

And like everyone says on the internet, to access the image I simply do in my html file

```
<img src="show_image.php?id=1" />
```

**Results**

When I call the php code (or go directly to the path /show_image.php?id=1) I get a message that says "The image [URL] cannot be displayed because it contains errors". (I did Google and DuckDuckGo this error many times.)

The closest I came to make it work is when I comment the line that says *header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');* I can see the binary code (converted in characters) for the image. Although when I check the properties of the page, it changed from image/jpeg to text/html (like expected)

I also tried replacing the *echo $image;* by

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
$imagejpeg($img);
$imagedestroy($img);
```

but it does not work either.

**EDIT - Inserting image in DB**

```
if (isset ($_FILES) && is_array($_FILES)) {
    $filename = $_FILES['team-logo']['name'][0];
    $filesize = $_FILES['team-logo']['size'][0];
    $filetype = $_FILES['team-logo']['type'][0];

    if (substr($filetype,0,5) == "image") {
        $imagedata = $mysqli->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['team-logo']['tmp_name'][0]));
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">You need to select and image</p>';
    }
}

if (empty($error_msg)) {
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli("INSERT INTO `teams` (`id`, `image`, `mime`) VALUES ('', ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $imagedata, $filetype);
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            //Display error
        }
        //Else image was inserted successfully 
    }
}
```

Does any one have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you making sure no other stuff is being echoed before/after the image, as i do not see you exiting right after echoing the image. Also have you made sure the image was saved properly to the database?

Comment: what stored in your teams.image? binary data?

Comment: As a basic test, locally save the image you request from the server. Check if that can be opened without problems or is the viewer complains as well. I have the suspect that your image _is_ indeed corrupt. This _might_ be an encoding issue. You'd have to post your table setup for this.

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem, but be aware that you should not be encoding your database parameters twice (with both `real_escape_string` and binding).

Comment: @vp_arth The image is save as a medium_blob
the table has the following : id->int (11), image->mediumblob, mime->varchar(10)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I can confirm you that there is no other echo in the file. I just placed a line with **exit;** right after the **echo $image;** and I still have the same problem

Comment: Then more than likely the image data was corrupted when it was saved into the database, what does the code that puts the file into the database look like

Comment: @PatrickEvans I updated the question with the code for inserting in the database. (I hope I did something wrong in this part) :-)

Comment: Don't you have to convert it into an object?  Something like `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode(ob_get_clean()) . '">`

Also double check there is no whitespace at the end of your php files.

Comment: @KevinO'Brien No, OP is doing it right

Comment: @AndrewMedico actually, I think it **is** the cause of the problem :)

Comment: Yes, now that the insert code has been posted that appears to be true. When we only had the display code, it appeared harmless since the `id` would be purely numeric and not affected by extra escaping.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me understand the problem. I marked it as resolved after the explanation from @Phil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most probably because you are escaping the binary data using `real_escape_string` and then storing it via a bound parameter.

Change your *insert* code to the following...

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents($_FILES['team-logo']['tmp_name'][0]);

// snip

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli("INSERT INTO `teams` (`image`, `mime`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $imagedata, $filetype);
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
        //Display error
    }
    //Else image was inserted successfully 
}
```

To illustrate the problem, say your binary data contained the following...

```
1234'5678
```

Running this through `real_escape_string` would produce something like this

```
1234\'5678
```

or

```
1234''5678
```

depending on how MySQL feels like escaping the strings at the time.

When you bind this to your *insert* statement, those escape characters will be *literally* stored, thus corrupting your binary data.

Binding parameters is the safest way to inject values into queries. You do **not** need to sanitise those value strings for safe use within a query.

Comment: Amazing, I made it work by removing the real_escape_string like you said. Thank you as well for the explanation after the PHP code.